# Duda con los métodos especiales y atributos especiales

Tags: python, python-3.x

En python se usan los llamados atributos especiales como el __name__ , así que un día me pregunte, porque no puedo usar este método de la siguiente forma:

```
.name
```

lo mismo pasa con los métodos, métodos como __str__(), porque no los puedo usar como .str(), o porque si print() es una función como str(), porque a el print() no le puedo poner barras bajas? -> __print()__

En Internet me entere de algo llamado métodos y atributos especiales.

Así que ya explicada mi duda, me podrían decir:

- cual es la diferencia entre los métodos y atributos especiales con los métodos y atributos normales?
- cuando usar métodos especiales a cambio de los métodos normales, y cuando usar atributos especiales en vez de atributos normales?
- porque usar métodos y atributos especiales?
- porque en python esta __str__() si ya existe str()?
- porque el print() no se puede declarar entre barras bajas, como también el __name__ no se puede declarar sin ellas?
- porque se llaman métodos y atributos especiales (A que viene ese "especial")?

Comment: mucho de lo que preguntas estan en la docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Al contrario, `str` devuelve `type(object).__str__(object)`, es decir, es lo mismo que llamar a la función `__str__` del objeto. Puedes consultarlo en [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str). No lo escribo como respuesta ya que solo quería responder la pregunta **¿Por qué en python está __str__() si ya existe str()?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los atributos y métodos especiales(magic methods) usan doble guión bajo por ejemplo:

```
__name__
__str__
__init__
__call__
__del__
```

Cuando utilizas **.name** estas llamando un atributo de un objeto por ejemplo:

```
class Persona:
    nombre = "Carlos"
```

Para llamar al atributo nombre utlizamos el punto así **.name** despues de instanciar `Persona`:

```
>>> p = Persona()
>>> print(p.name)
Carlos
```

El anterior código imprimirá el contenido del atributo `nombre`del objeto `p`.

Python utliza métodos y atributos especiales para llamarlos en ciertas ocasiones por ejemplo cuando se inicializa un objeto se llama a `__init__`. Otro ejemplo es cuando python llama a `__name__` para saber si el programa se corre como programa principal o si es un módulo importado.

> cual es la diferencia entre los métodos y atributos especiales con los métodos y atributos normales?

Se podría decir que los métodos normales llaman a los métodos especiales:

Por ejemplo el método `len()` llama al método especial `__len__` del objeto.
Si modificaramos el método especial `__len__` de la clase Persona de la siguiente forma:

```py
class Persona:
    def __len__():
        return 1
```

Se obtiene el siguiente resultado cuando se utiliza la función `len()`:

```
>>> p = Persona()
>>> len(p)
1
```

> porque usar métodos y atributos especiales?

Cuando quieras cambiar el comportamiento de un objeto como en el ejemplo anterior

> porque se llaman métodos y atributos especiales (A que viene ese "especial")

Son utilizados para especificar las caracteristicas de un objeto y python lo usa internamente.

Comment: eso de que len() y print() son globales que tiene que ver con que len () sea especial y print(), no?

Comment: globales y privadas?

Comment: def len(var):
 return 1          //no puedo hacer esto en vez de __len__()???

Answer (score 0):

En realidad si puedes hacerlo, aunque hay que agregar un poco de código a la clase

```
class DottetAttrib(object):
```

internamente `__getattr__` llama a `__getattribute__` con los mismos parámetros

```
  def __getattr__(self, name):

    # Comprobamos si existe el atributo, de existir lo devolvemos
    if name in self.__dir__():
      print(name, ' in dir')
      return self.__getattribute__(name)

    # Comprobamos si existe el attributo privado, si existe lo devolvemos
    if f"__{name}__" in self.__dir__():
      return self.__getattribute__(f"__{name}__")

    # si no se da ninguno de los casos anteriores, devolvemos un error
    else:
      raise AttributeError(f"'{self.__class__.__name__}' object has no attribute '{name}'")

a = DottetAttrib()
b = ''
print(a.dict)
print(a.dir())
print(a.__dir__())
print(b.__class__.__name__)

# Estos dos dan error de atributo
print(a.hola)
print(b.__name__)
```

Ahora bien ¿que sucede con estos métodos?
Python tiene un comportamiento especial con estos métodos (de ahí su nombre)
por ejemplo `print(clase)` llama al método especial `__repr__` `for` llama a `__iter__` y así mas cosas.

Existe una metodología llamada sobrecarga de operadores, puedes verlo por ejemplo en el modulo Path de la librería pathlib donde para unir directorios basta con "dividirlos"
ejemplo:

```
ruta = Path('/home/usuario")
documentos = ruta / 'Documentos' # quedaría como '/home/usuario/Documentos'
```

esto lo logran redefiniendo el método `__truediv__` que es el que llama python para dividir

si agregamos el metodo `__truediv__` a la clase `DottetAttrib`, podemos hacer lo mismo:

```
def __truediv__(self, value):
    return f'Quieres que divida por {value}'

print(a / 7)
print(a / 'otra cosa')
```

sabiendo como funcionan los métodos especiales puedes hacer cosas muy chulas